# Trying to downgrade MongoDB on CentOS

Tags: centos, mongodb, glibc

I'm running CentOS 6.7 on a Hyper-V, which means that I can't do an in-place upgrade to 7.0.  Today I did a server restart, and some time between the last time I did a restart and today my installation of MongoDB was upgraded to the latest version (3.0.6).  I don't know who did the update, but now it requires some libraries which the current version of CentOS can't support, as evidenced by the following:

```
$ sudo bin/mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbPath=/media/DataExt/mongodb-wiredtiger-data/
bin/mongod: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by bin/mongod)
bin/mongod: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by bin/mongod)
bin/mongod: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by bin/mongod)
bin/mongod: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by bin/mongod)
bin/mongod: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by bin/mongod)
```

I've tried to dumb down MongoDB to 3.0.5 (and then to 3.0.4, and then all the way to 3.0.0) using the sudo yum downgrade... commands for all of the modules (mongodb-org-server, mongodb-org-mongos, mongodb-org-shell, and mongodb-org-tools), and when I try to start mongod I still get the same errors.

Is there something else I have to do to get MongoDB to work with the C and C++ libraries I have?  The maximum I can support for this version of the OS is GLIBCXX_3.4.13, GLIBC_3.4.13, and CXXABI_1.3.3.

Comment: Ha! Downgrading MongoDB. That's funny. Thumbs up for the laugh today! :D

Comment: Apparently I don't have the level of savvy required to appreciate my own joke.  Can you help in parsing the punchline?

Answer (score 1):

Spin up a new VM and install the correct version of MongoDB and it's dependencies. Then copy the data from he old machine to the new.

If you don't know how it got upgraded then, on the old system look in `/var/log/yum.log` to see when it happened. Then take a look at all the system cron jobs, the smoking gun will be yumcron.

You can obviously disable yumcron or you can edit /etc/yum.conf to exclude certain packages.

Comment: I suppose this could be done.  There's a large amount of other stuff that would have to be migrated over to the new VM, but I could just as easily start the new VM with the newest CentOS version, which would obviate the need for a lower version.  What I don't understand is why the lower version of MongoDB still has these more advanced dependencies when it didn't before the update.